# C# Validate if all variables have been filled before exiting a Form

Tags: c#

following Problem
I have a WinForm App where I will set variables, here only string, decimal or int, through User-Input. This happens by entering values in textboxes, or setting values in textboxes with buttons (increasing and decreasing). Also there are two checkbox pairs (2x yes/no). The checkboxes save a string in my needed values as well.

After the value is typed into the textbox, or has been set to the right number, the User presses a save button (one button for each value, in total 6 save buttons). The save-button always makes sure the correct value has been entered beofre saving

Before closing the form, I want to check if all my needed values have been filled and if not, tell the user: hey, you forgot that certain value. How can I accomplish that? In my example I would want to check if Height, Unit and No_of _measure have been filled with a value. I could just trhow it all into a big "if" with logical "or" in it (about 14 values in total), but then I dont get the specific value that is missing, should one be not filled in (to tell the user)

example:

```
    public decimal Height { get; private set; }
    public int No_of_measure { get; private set; }
    public string Unit { get; private set; }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Save the rough heigth
    {                                                     
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        { MessageBox.Show("No value detected in [Current Height] Window. Please Click Start first!"); }
        else
        {
            Height = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //save no. of measurements
    {
        if (textBox5.Text == "")
        { MessageBox.Show("Please enter a value"); }
        else
        { No_of_measure = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text); }
    }

    private void checkBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //save Unit mm
    {
        if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            checkBox4.Checked = false;
            Unit = "mm";
        }
        label22.Text = "mm";
        label23.Text = "mm";
```

Comment: Is this a windows forms app, web app?

Comment: its a WinForm app. I'll put it into the description

Comment: can you please post the condition what you have tried

Comment: ...  Why don't you set up an individual IF statement to check each value, and provide specific feedback to the user?

Comment: @vickyS well thats where my problem is. Don't really have an idea how to solve it, thats why I'm asking for help =) I tried putting all values in one if, but then its really long and messy, and doesnt show the specific value that is missing. My second idea was to create counter values for each save button (set button value to 1 for example when pressed succesfully), and check if all save buttons have been pressed succesfully, but sometimes one save button saves more than one value, and checkboxes dont have a save button.

Comment: @Taegost so in the exit button set up like 14 specific If statements for each value? I was hoping there was a cleaner solution to this =) but guess I'll try it that way for now.

Comment: somehow we need to iterate all the controls which are mandatory, so we can try if you expose all your controls here

Comment: @Chris - Any way you approach the problem, you're going to have to set up individualized paths for each field to meet your requirement of giving the user relevant feedback.  Sometimes the simplest solution is the best, IMHO there's really no reason to over-engineer such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to how to check for null in multiple properties, a rough way would be to store your values in a Dictionary where you can run a linq query as below.. This would require you to make major changes to your form.

```
    // properties dictionary populate with your values
    Dictionary<string,string> _propertiesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private bool PropertyChecks()
    {
        return _propertiesDictionary.Any(x => x.Value == null);
    }
```

You can create a form_closing event method and put any logic you require inside of this, example..

```
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChecks())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some properties are null");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i guess you just created a dictionary and have not added any properties to it.

Comment: Correct, Sorry I was in a rush.. they would populate this first with some empty values using correct key as identifier

Comment: but i dont think this will work because we do need to update this dictionary whenever we are updating the property